# how to change UIKit UIImage:drawInRect method to AppKIt NSImage:drawInRect Method

Tags: cocoa

i'm porting an iphone app to Mac app,there i have to change all the UIKit related class to AppKit. 
if you can help me on this really appreciate. is this the best way to do below part..

Iphone App-->using UIKit

```
UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
[image drawInRect:rect];
UIGraphicsPopContext();
```

Mac Os--Using AppKit

```
[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
NSGraphicsContext * nscg = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:ctx flipped:YES];
[NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:nscg];
NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(offset.x * scale, offset.y * scale, scale * size.width, scale * size.height);
[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

[image drawInRect:rect fromRect:NSMakeRect( 0, 0, [image size].width, [image size].height )
        operation:NSCompositeClear
         fraction:1.0];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/) and [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/ObjC_classic/) are your friends; they'll explain a lot of things that you're misusing here.

> ```
> [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
> NSGraphicsContext * nscg = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:ctx flipped:YES];
> [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:nscg];
> ```

You save the graphics state in the current context, and then immediately create a new context and set it as current.

> ```
> NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(offset.x * scale, offset.y * scale, scale * size.width, scale * size.height);
> ```

This is apparently all you gsaved for. Creating a rectangle is not affected by the gstate, since it isn't a drawing operation (the rectangle is just a set of numbers; you're not *drawing* a rectangle here).

Furthermore, you should use the current [transformation matrix](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAffineTransform_AppKitAdditions/) for the scale.

> ```
> [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
> ```

And then you grestore in the context you created, not the one you gsaved in.

[Edit] Looking at this again a year and a half later, I think you misinterpreted the `saveGraphicsState` and `restoreGraphicsState` methods as a counterpart to `UIGraphicsPushContext` and `UIGraphicsPopContext`. They're not; `saveGraphicsState` and `restoreGraphicsState` push and pop the graphics state *of the current context*. The current context is separately controlled (`setCurrentContext:`) and does not have a push/pop API. [/Edit]

I'm assuming that you're in a CALayer's `drawInContext:` method? If this is in an NSView, then you already have a current context and don't need to (and shouldn't) create one.

> ```
> [image drawInRect:rect fromRect:NSMakeRect( 0, 0, [image size].width, [image size].height )
>         operation:NSCompositeClear
>          fraction:1.0];
> ```

[The `NSCompositeClear` operation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCompositeClear) clears the destination pixels, like the Eraser tool in your favorite paint program. It does not draw the image. You want [the `NSCompositeSourceOver` operation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCompositeSourceOver).

Comment: For future reference: The _instance_ methods `-[NSGraphicsContext save|restoreGraphicsState]` indeed push/pop the graphics state of the receiver of these messages. However, the _class_ methods `+[NSGraphicsContext save|restoreGraphicsState]` with the same name do push/pop _contexts_.